# iframe query string

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have got the values by passing the query string in an iframe.`src = "xyxz.jsp?name="+name+"&pass="+pass+"&id="+id`.

I need to pass those values which i have got to another jsp page
`<iframe src="xyz.jsp"></iframe>`

How can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "another jsp page"? Please add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, but I guess that you want to pass the querystring of the parent JSP page to the JSP page which is in an `iframe` of the parent JSP page. If so, then just print [`HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29):

```
<iframe src="page.jsp?${pageContext.request.queryString}"></iframe>
```

That said, iframes are an extremely bad practice and very clumsy when all the pages are located at the same server. Rather use server side includes using `<jsp:include>`. This way the included JSP has access to the *same* request object.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to dynamically change the src attribute of frame

```
function changeSrc()
{ 
  window.frames['testframe'].src = "xyxz.jsp?name="+name+"&pass="+pass+"&id="+id;
 }
```

Is this what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

according to your cooment to @Manjoor post  you want to call javascript function which is defined inside iframe and pass the parameters to it, if that so check this post
[Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)